# C++ static_cast and virtual method functionality

Tags: c++, virtual, static-cast

```
if ((char*)fixtureAData == "PLATFORM" && (char*)fixtureBData == "WEAPON"){
    static_cast<Weapon*>(contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData())->SetLethality(false);
```

This is a snippet of code from a team project I'm currently working on.

I was wondering about the functionality of `static_cast` on derived classes.

`SetLethality` is a method of `Weapon`, if I replace it with a virtual void called `PlatformCollide`, and create a version of that void in my dagger class, will the derived function be called? or does `static_cast` not work like that?

Comment: Just curious, why won't you write it and check?

Comment: `(char*)fixtureAData == "PLATFORM"` this likely doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @shuttle87 exactly. It probably works for them [by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) - I assume `fixtureAData` is initialized using the same string literal.

Comment: @eszeikial What is the return type of `GetUserData()`?

Comment: Use `std::string`. And yes, before you complain about efficiency: it's *efficient*.

Comment: looking at the coding style and immediately apparent logic errors in these 2 lines of code, I would say that this project is doomed to fail. Clean it up now before it's too late.

Comment: So, this wasn't my portion of code, and I'm not too happy with it myself. I'm just ducking my head in here to make some changes. 

the getUserData thing is working, as is evidenced by the rest of the code in this class, which I will not share to spare your eyes. 

Dave answered my question, I'm trying it out right now.

Comment: @shuttle87 and lethal-guitar I'm curious about the cast to char* now, it works, but I'm assuming its bad code for some reason? Care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `(char*)fixtureAData == "PLATFORM"` compares 2 pointers, it does not compare 2 strings. You need to use [`strcmp` or `strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). This may work if your compiler uses string pooling and `fixtureAData` is also assigned to the string literal `"PLATFORM"`, but this isn't a good/safe assumption.

Second: If you are casting a derived class to one of its base classes (as I'm guessing you're doing, but it's not clear) and then calling a virtual function on that base class, it will indeed use the vtable to find the most derived function to call. Please clarify you're question if I'm making a false assumption about what you're doing.

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking. I'm going to look up vtable because I have no clue what that is haha.